# Uncaught Type Error Opening Dialog

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I coding in Polymer 2 and am trying to open a paper dialog component when a function runs:

```
_boundListener(e) {
  this.error = e.detail;
  console.log(this.error);
  this.$.dialog.open();
}
```

I have verieifed that this.error is running and contains the correct data. I have a paper dialog in my template with the id of dialog however when this function runs I get the following message:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined

Any ideas? TIA

This function runs when an event listener get triggered. That listener is fired from this function:

```
  testError(e) {
    const err = e.detail.request.xhr.response.message;
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('_GEtesterror', {bubbles: true, detail: err}));
  }
```

I had to use window.dispatchEvent to fire this event as it was not bubbling up to the html where the dialog is. This might be why it is unable to find this.$.dialog?

This what the listener functions look like:

```
connectedCallback() {
  super.connectedCallback();
  window.addEventListener('_GEtesterror', this._boundListener);
  this._boundListener.bind(this);
}
disconnectedCallback() {
  super.disconnectedCallback();
  window.removeEventListener('error', this._boundListener);
}
_boundListener(e) {
  this.error = e.detail;
  console.log(this, this.$);
  this.$.dialog.open();
}
```

Comment: so the error is saying that `this.$` is undefined

Comment: it seems to be complaining about what ever I put after the $

Comment: because `$` is not defined in `this`....   `console.log(this.$); // undefined` My guess is `this` is not what you think it is

Comment: `this.$` is undefined. try to find  out how to call the `$`

Comment: that's how I am referencing the paper dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because `this.$` is undefined.

Use `console.log(this, this.$)` to determine the scope, where the function was called. Your listener is called with a wrong scope.

Also, **bind** your _boundListener to the correct scope:

```
connectedCallback() {
  super.connectedCallback();
  window.addEventListener('_GEtesterror', this._boundListener.bind(this));
}
disconnectedCallback() {
  super.disconnectedCallback();
  window.removeEventListener('error', this._boundListener.bind(this));
}
_boundListener(e) {
  this.error = e.detail;
  console.log(this, this.$);
  this.$.dialog.open();
}
```

Comment: that prints "Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}"

Comment: Can you post more of your code? It would be helpful to determine the root cause of your problem.

Comment: my listener is called here:

connectedCallback() {
      super.connectedCallback();
      window.addEventListener('_GEtesterror', this._boundListener);
      console.log("connectedCallback ran");
    }

Comment: Try adding your _boundListener function with .bind in the connectedCallback function, like this: `this._boundListener.bind(this)`.

Comment: I have added that line to the _boundListener function and the error is the same - I have added my listener functions to the latest edit

Comment: this has worked. Thank you for your help, I hope to be able to pay it forward!